# how to create association instance from source instance with sequelize-typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I have 1:n association `Company -> CompanySettings`,
what I want is, I find Company by Id then create companySettings by that instance and automatically fill the foreign key attribute

`using sequelize-typescript`

I have tried `$get`, `$add`, `$count` from association function and its works

but when I try `$create` function it gives me the errors

Company Class

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'company',
})
export class Company extends Model<Company> {

  @Column({ allowNull: false, type: DataType.STRING(50) })
  name: string

  @CreatedAt
  @Column({ field: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date

  @UpdatedAt
  @Column({ field: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: Date

  @Column({ field: 'is_deleted', defaultValue: 'f', type: DataType.BOOLEAN })
  isDeleted: boolean

  @HasMany(() => CompanySettings)
  settings: CompanySettings[]
```

CompanySettings class

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'company_settings',
})
export class CompanySettings extends Model<CompanySettings> {

  @ForeignKey(() => Company)
  @Column
  idCompany: number

  @BelongsTo(() => Company)
  company: Company

  @Column({ type: DataType.ENUM('default', 'alwaysApprove', 'alwaysAsking') })
  defaultBookingApproval: defaultBookingOptions

  @Column({ type: DataType.SMALLINT })
  budgetPeriod: number

  @Column({ type: DataType.CHAR(2) })
  startDate: string

  @CreatedAt
  @Column
  createdAt: Date

  @UpdatedAt
  @Column
  updatedAt: Date

  @Column({ defaultValue: 'f', type: DataType.BOOLEAN })
  isDeleted: boolean
```

controller

```
const companies = await Company.findOne()

    return await companies.$create('settings', { startDate: '22' })
```

After finding the source instance, I want to create new instance related to the source instance

But the errors I got is shown below

```
TypeError: this[("create" + string_1.capitalize(...))] is not a function
```

tell me where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want create one setting, you should write code like below

`companies.$create('setting', { startDate: '22 })`

instead of
`companies.$create('settings', { startDate: '22' })`

if you want create bulk, you should like below

`companies.$create('settings', [{ startDate: '22', { startDate: '23'}] })`

Answer (score 0):

fuzes solutions should work nicely,

If you want to attach this newly created instance to source instance then:

```
const setting = await companies.$create('setting', { startDate: '22' });
companies.set('settings', [...companies.settings, setting]);
```